# linear layout not scrolling horizontally when populated programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I am working on a layout where i have to populate textView programmaticaly inside a vertical linear layout . But some of my textView contents are too wide for my screen size and they are not being visible . This is my layout

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="320px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/diff_layout"
            android:layout_width="320px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

And here is the code where i am programatically populating the linear layout :-

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.diff_layout);

    String[] splitLines = content.split("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<splitLines.length;i++){
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setSingleLine(true);
        textView.setLines(1);
        //textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        textView.setText(splitLines[i]);
        //textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));
        textView.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        /*textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);*/
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
```

Please tell me where am i doing things wrong

Comment: Dont set a width to your HorizontalScrollview

Comment: Try to put layout_width="wrap_content" in your HorizontalScrollView and LinearLayout

Comment: What you will reach if you used vertical layout inside horizontal scroll ? just try to add textView to scroll view directly.

Comment: @ARP I have tried using wrap_content in my horizontalScrollView and LinearLayout . but it didn't work

Comment: Same goes for the Root scroll view. Don't set it to match_parent.

Comment: @sarthakGandhi tried that also. Didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much hit and trial , i came up with the right solution :-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/diff_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and my java snippet :-

> LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)
>   findViewById(R.id.diff_layout);
>
> ```
>     String[] splitLines = content.split("\n");
>     for(int i=0;i<splitLines.length;i++){
>         TextView textView = new TextView(this);
>         textView.setText(splitLines[i]);
>         textView.setMaxLines(1);
>         textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
>         linearLayout.addView(textView);
>     }
> ```